# Powershell text string to CSV

Tags: string, powershell, csv, wildcard

I initially thought this problem more complex than it actuially is but after digging around I still cant seem to find a solution that I can re-purpose. I'm trying to use wildcards but perhaps I'm going about this the wrong way

#### I have a text file as below:

```
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Wed Aug 13 14:20:22 2014
Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Real Application Clusters, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP,
Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

EXTERNAL ID

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

'M1

---


12345678-1

M07


18765432-1

M14

19638527-1

M14



EXTERNAL ID

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

'M1

---


17418529-1

M07
```

#### I would like a single CSV with 2 columns such as:

```
EXTERNAL ID     M01

12345678-1      M07

18765432-1      M14

19638527-1      M14

17418529-1      M07
```

Any insight or help is appreciated

Comment: Your desired CSV would be space delimited and have three column headers not two the way that you have it written. I think I know what you want, but it would be nice if you were precise in your request. It would also be nice if you posted what you have tried and explained what didn't work about it.

Comment: Yeah, we can help you but this sample isn't specific enough. For example there is a tick mark in front of `M1`. Is that intentional? Do you want it stripped out or kept?

Comment: @EBGreen - Apologise for the formatting, I've been staring at this for most of today and I think just blurted out things I'd tried rather than show productive steps.

Comment: @George Mauer - That Tick before M1 was exported with the query. The only alteration I made were the " " around the hyphens as they were changing the font to bold. Ideally removing it but if I could produce any 2 column formatted CSV at all I would be delighted. I can change/strip the headers after

Comment: is the edit correct? do you want to keep the ticks or not?

Comment: Just by way of how to ask questions - it is much easier to answer these if you give precisely what you want in addition to an example. "Starting with the 7th line, and ignoring any lines that begin with hyphens format every other line into 2 columns"

Comment: @George Mauer - Thanks for the input. I will certanily be more spesific next time. The way I was approaching it was 
Any string begining (8numbers + hyphen + 1numebr) would be parced to a hash table [0] 
Any sting following that begining with ("M" + 2numbers)would be parced to hash table [1]
Then export the table to a CSV in two columns 

I'm currently trying to edit the below answers to get it correct. But I've got two columns in a CSV so it's a great start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something that I think will do what I want. It could probably be made more efficient and smaller but I went for easy to read and comprehend instead:

```
$res = @()
$content = get-content SomeFile.txt | ?{($_ -ne 'EXTERNAL ID') -AND (-NOT $_.StartsWith('"-')) -AND ($_ -ne "'M1") -AND (-NOT $_.Startswith('SQL*')) -AND ($_ -ne '')}

for($count = 0; $count -lt $content.Count; $count = $count + 2){
    $id = $content[$count]
    $m = $content[$count + 1]
    $temp = New-Object PSCustomObject -Property @{'External ID' = $id;
                                                  'M01' = $m;
    }
    $res += $temp
}
$res | Export-CSV .\Som\Path\Name.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: I butchered your beautiful code but I'm delighted to say i used this answer as a building block and my program now works like a dream (all but slow but thats my inefficient coding). Thanks for your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

Similar to EBGreen's answer, but simpler I think.

```
$Col2=$false
gc c:\temp\test.txt |Select -skip 6| ?{![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_) -and $_ -notmatch "^(---|External|'M1)"} | %{
    If($Col2){
        [PSCustomObject][Ordered]@{
            'External ID'=$Col1
            "'M1"=$_}
        $Col2=$false
        }else{
            $Col1=$_
            $Col2=$true
        }
    } | Export-Csv C:\temp\New.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thank you for this, there was slight issues when trying to run it against my files and due to my lack of experience in reading PS alis's I couldnt sucessfully alter this so went with EBGreens answer. Thanks again for the time and help with formatting the question.